# Drupal: Best place to put drupal_goto

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-6

I need to redirect certain content types to other nodes.

As a proof of concept I've got this working with a `drupal_goto` at the top of `node--[type].tpl.php`

This works great, but is probably the least optimized place to put it.

Would `phptemplate_preprocess_node` be too early?
What about `hook_nodeapi, $op='view'`?

Where's the smartest place to put a drupal_goto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_nodeapi`'s `view` hook is where I'd put it, yeah. It's going to be one of the first spots you'll have the `$node` variable to inspect for the node types you're redirecting.